# Do I need an Apache server for my Django site?

Tags: django, apache

I'm making a Django site and I get this error after typing `./manage.py shell` into my Ubuntu command line:

```
/home/deanna/django_test/static/
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./manage.py", line 10, in <module>
execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/home/deanna/django-deanna/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Django-1.7.4-py2.7.egg/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 385, in execute_from_command_line
utility.execute()
  File "/home/deanna/django-deanna/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Django-1.7.4-py2.7.egg/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 354, in execute
django.setup()
  File "/home/deanna/django-deanna/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Django-1.7.4-py2.7.egg/django/__init__.py", line 20, in setup
configure_logging(settings.LOGGING_CONFIG, settings.LOGGING)
 File "/home/deanna/django-deanna/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Django-1.7.4-py2.7.egg/django/utils/log.py", line 87, in configure_logging
logging_config_func(logging_settings)
 File "/usr/lib/python2.7/logging/config.py", line 794, in dictConfig
dictConfigClass(config).configure()
 File "/usr/lib/python2.7/logging/config.py", line 627, in configure
'%r: %s' % (name, e))
ValueError: Unable to configure logger 'django_request': Unable to add handler 'request_handler': 'request_handler'
```

After much research on SO and the Internet, I am wondering if installing an Apache server would fix this error? I have`gunicorn` installed but is that enough to run a Django site?

Edit: This is my amazon s3 part of `settings.py`:

```
try:
    from local_settings import *
except Exception as e:
    print e.message 

if not DEBUG:
    AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME = os.environ['AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME']
    AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID = os.environ['AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID']
    STATICFILES_STORAGE = 'storages.backends.s3boto.S3BotoStorage'
    DEFAULT_FILE_STORAGE = 'storages.backends.s3boto.S3BotoStorage'
    S3_URL = 'http://%s.s3.amazonaws.com/assets/' % AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME 
    STATIC_URL = S3_URL
```

Comment: Whether or not Apache is a good idea to run your actual site, you certainly don't need it to run the shell.

Comment: So you're saying that the lack of an Apache server isn't causing my error? Do you need an Apache server to deploy the site though?

Comment: For deployment you should go with a webserver such as Apache. During development/testing the built in webserver would suffice. Is this question any different from the previous three questions you posted in the last 24 hours?

Comment: After doing some research, I came up with the hypothesis that perhaps the lack of a server is causing my error.

Comment: Gunicorn can't serve static files if you're using it for production, you need nginx to serve them or use some service like amazon s3. http://gunicorn-docs.readthedocs.org/en/latest/deploy.html

Comment: I'm using amazon s3, as is shown in `settings.py`.

Comment: Please post your `settings.LOGGING` from your settings.py file. Django is failing when it is trying to create your log configuration - so I suspect it is something wrong there..

Answer (score 0):

`./manage.py shell` does not rely on Apache. Your error comes from elsewhere.

I see that you are trying to use Django libraries located in your home directory. What about installing Django properly with pip?

```
pip install Django
```

Comment: The `Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): django in /home/deanna/django-deanna/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Django-1.7.4-py2.7.egg` so Django is installed properly.